# Getting GET request insted of POST in PHP

Tags: php

I'm creating update password page in php but getting problem i.e. insted of post request i'm getting get. i'm using post method in form. why this happen
please help

here is my code

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['add'])){

if(empty($_POST['add'])){
    $error='Username or Password did not match';
}
else
{

    $password=$_POST['pass'];
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Connection fail");
    $db=mysql_select_db("chanshal", $connection);
    $result=mysql_query("UPDATE login SET password='$password' where id=1", $connection );
    echo 'Entered data succesfully';
    mysql_close($connection);
}
}


$title='Change Password';
$content='
<div class="gallery-box">
        <form action="" method="post">
        <label style="padding-right:50px;">Password</label> <input type="password" name="pass" value="">

        <br />
        <br />
        <label style="padding-right:50px;">New Password</label> <input type="password" name="new-pass" value="">
        <br />
        <br />
        <input style="width:150px;" name="add" type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
        </div>
```

';
         include 'admin-template.php';

Comment: using mysql_ is evil, your code is wide open to sql injection!

Comment: So the form values are passing in the URL? You can see them in the $_GET variable? Can you post the rest of your code?

Comment: yes it is passing in url

Comment: Try adding enctype parameter to form tag, so you would have <form action="" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">. See http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp.

Comment: are you sure it is passing in URL? what URL you got?

Comment: You get a free downvote....

Comment: http://localhost:8080/chanshal%20php/admin/changepassword.php?pass=mb&new-pass=&add=Update This is the url im getting

Comment: Indra Kumar if you know then please tell me why i'm gettin get request while i am using post request method

Comment: It will never happen.... And your submit type is also getting passed????

Comment: @IndraKumarS I am getting the prob. Ypu please use this code once and then tell me

Comment: what is there in admin-template.php

Comment: Should i send you the complete code?

Answer (score 1):

You are taking `$_POST['pass']`, but the new password field has the name `new-pass` in your form:

```
$password=$_POST['pass'];
```

---

```
<input type="password" name="new-pass" value="">
```

So I would say your POST request is working fine, you just update your table with the same data all the time.

Comment: this is not the reason for get request.
i am facing problem with request method

Comment: i am getting all my data in url